# Why can't I use mysql_real_escape_string with zend framework's update() method?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm having trouble with Zend Db's `update()` method. It's not safe against sql injection on its own.

Select methods seem safe, so I could theoretically do a select and then simply do a `save()` after modifying the fields I want to update. But, I don't want to have to run 2 queries - a select followed by an update, just to run an update. That doesn't seem efficient.

To solve this, I tried to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but it actually caused the data I was trying to update to got into the database as an empty string. Not sure why.

Here is the code:

```
public function updateMyTable($data,$id){
    $safeData=array();
    foreach($data as $field=>$val){
        $safeData[$field] = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
    }
    $where[]= 'id = '.mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    self::instance()->update($safeData,$where)
}
```

Does anyone know if I have something incorrect that is causing the blank database entry? Or, a way to safely use `update()`? I didn't want to use Zend's `quote()` method because it actually puts slashes into my data in the database. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it's open to SQL injection? I'm not saying it's not, I'm just wondering why you think this.

Comment: For instance, if you use [`Pdo_Mysql`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html), you don't need to escape strings on your own.

Comment: Good point. I went back to the reference manual and it doesn't actually say it's not escaped, although it talks about using quote() which I mistakenly thought was for escaping data. Maybe there is mo issue. I'll try an injection and see what happens. Thanks!!

Comment: I tried to do a sql injection to the update() statement, and was not able to get it to happen. Doesn't seem to be an issue. You were correct, Jared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` needs a connection to the database opened by `mysql_connect` to work, and if the framework uses another driver e.g. `mysqli` it will fail to escape the string with this function. look for the documentation, there should be a special method for escaping data within the framework.

Comment: Ah, thank you for explaining why it doesn't work. I am unable to find an escaping method that doesn't actually add slashes to data in database. Hoping someone will know one and post it.

Comment: Is there any alternative (something like `mysql_real_escape_string`) for ZEND?

Answer (score 3):

When you update a Model in Zend Framework you should write a code like this:

```
$Values = array(
   'Col1' => $this->Attr1,
   'Col2' => $this->Attr2
);

$RowChanged = $Db->update('table_name', $Values, $Db->quoteInto('Id = ?', $this->Id));
```

Comment: [quoteInto() documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.quoting.quote-into).

Comment: I tried this but it actually added slashes to my data in the database working more like addslashes() than mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: @user902545 Using the update method in this way is a good and safe method. It'll defend you from the sql injection. Besides, when you retrieve the data, you'll not get the extra slash.